Pine Script Levels and Ranges - Visualization losses some levels when displaying range levels
Chart ImageFirst, I would like to point out that I am not a coder, I have a personal working script that I developed with the help of AI.  The script is designed to visualize support/resistance and range levels for on TradingView. It takes my user-defined inputs for support and resistance, including major levels and ranges, and plots these levels on the chart with different visual styles depending on  whether they are major or normal levels.
The script identifies ranges by detecting hyphens in the input, indicating a lower and upper bound (e.g., 5593-5588). It processes these bounds, checks for a "major" designation, and stores the ranges separately. When drawing, the script creates shaded boxes representing these ranges on the chart, with color and transparency indicating whether they are support or resistance levels and if they are major. It has an option to turn the range visualization on and off.
The problem that I am having is that whenever the ranges are visualized, some of the support or resistance leaves disappear.  I cant't seem to get all the levels to display correctly when showing the ranges.
These are input levels used:
Support:
5593-5588 (major), 5582, 5572, 5567 (major), 5560, 5555, 5540-45 (major), 5528 (major), 5519, 5512 (major), 5502, 5498, 5490-58 (major), 5483, 5474 (major), 5464 (major), 5457, 5445-50 (major), 5438 (major), 5434, 5428, 5423 (major), 5414 (major), 5405-10, 5375-5385
Resistance:
5604 (major), 5610, 5623, 5630 (major), 5636, 5643, 5653 (major), 5661 (major), 5668, 5672, 5678, 5685 (major), 5694, 5702, 5705 (major), 5709, 5713, 5720 (major), 5730 (major), 5741 (major), 5753, 5765, 5787, 5796, 5801, 5806 (major), 5816, 5821, 5825 (major), 5831, 5836 (major), 5839, 5845 (major)
//@version=5
indicator("SPX Levels - Final Adjustment with Shading and Debug", overlay=true, max_bars_back=500)

// Define colors
color normalResistanceColor = color.red
color majorResistanceColor = color.orange
color normalSupportColor = color.green
color majorSupportColor = color.blue

// Input fields for levels
var string support_input = input.string(defval="5593-5588 (major), 5582, 5572, 5567 (major), 5560, 5555, 5540-45 (major), 5528 (major), 5519, 5512 (major), 5502, 5498, 5490-58 (major), 5483, 5474 (major), 5464 (major), 5457, 5445-50 (major), 5438 (major), 5434, 5428, 5423 (major), 5414 (major), 5405-10, 5375-5385", title="Support Levels", group="Daily Levels")
var string resistance_input = input.string(defval="5604 (major), 5610, 5623, 5630 (major), 5636, 5643, 5653 (major), 5661 (major), 5668, 5672, 5678, 5685 (major), 5694, 5702, 5705 (major), 5709, 5713, 5720 (major), 5730 (major), 5741 (major), 5753, 5765, 5787, 5796, 5801, 5806 (major), 5816, 5821, 5825 (major), 5831, 5836 (major), 5839, 5845 (major)", title="Resistance Levels", group="Daily Levels")
var bool show_debug = input.bool(defval=false, title="Show Debug Information", group="Display Options")
var bool show_ranges = input.bool(defval=true, title="Show Ranges", group="Display Options") // New input field to toggle range drawing on/off

// Function to expand abbreviated ranges
expand_range(level_string) =>
    is_major = str.contains(level_string, "(major)")
    range_parts = str.split(str.replace(level_string, "(major)", ""), "-")
    lower = str.tonumber(str.trim(array.get(range_parts, 0)))
    upper_str = str.trim(array.get(range_parts, 1))
    
    float upper = na
    if not na(upper_str)
        if str.contains(upper_str, ".")
            upper := str.tonumber(upper_str)
        else
            upper := str.tonumber(str.substring(str.tostring(lower), 0, str.length(str.tostring(lower)) - str.length(upper_str)) + upper_str)
    else
        upper := lower

    [lower, upper, is_major]

// Function to parse levels and separate ranges
parse_levels(input_string) =>
    levels = array.new_string(0)
    major_levels = array.new_string(0)
    ranges = array.new_string(0)
    major_ranges = array.new_string(0)
    extracted_ranges_str = ""
    level_strings = str.split(input_string, ",")
    for i = 0 to array.size(level_strings) - 1
        level = str.trim(array.get(level_strings, i))
        if str.contains(level, "-")
            [lower, upper, is_major] = expand_range(level)
            if not na(lower) and not na(upper)
                range_str = str.tostring(lower) + "-" + str.tostring(upper) + (is_major ? " (major)" : "")
                array.push(ranges, range_str)
                extracted_ranges_str := extracted_ranges_str + (extracted_ranges_str != "" ? ", " : "") + range_str
                if is_major
                    array.push(major_ranges, range_str)
        else
            array.push(levels, level)
            if str.contains(level, "(major)")
                array.push(major_levels, level)
    [levels, major_levels, ranges, major_ranges, extracted_ranges_str]

// Parse support and resistance levels
[support_levels, major_support_levels, support_ranges, major_support_ranges, support_extracted_ranges] = parse_levels(support_input)
[resistance_levels, major_resistance_levels, resistance_ranges, major_resistance_ranges, resistance_extracted_ranges] = parse_levels(resistance_input)

// Function to draw levels on the chart
draw_levels(levels, is_support) =>
    if array.size(levels) > 0
        for i = 0 to array.size(levels) - 1
            level = array.get(levels, i)
            is_major = str.contains(level, "(major)")
            price = str.tonumber(str.replace(level, "(major)", ""))
            if not na(price)
                line_style = is_major ? line.style_solid : line.style_dotted  // Adjusted line styles
                level_color = is_support ? (is_major ? majorSupportColor : normalSupportColor) : (is_major ? majorResistanceColor : normalResistanceColor)
                line.new(x1=bar_index[1], y1=price, x2=bar_index, y2=price, color=level_color, style=line_style, width=1, extend=extend.right)
                label.new(bar_index, price, text=str.tostring(price) + (is_major ? " (Major)" : ""), style=label.style_label_down, color=color.new(level_color, 0), textcolor=color.white)

// Function to draw ranges on the chart with shading
draw_ranges(ranges, is_support) =>
    if array.size(ranges) > 0
        for i = 0 to array.size(ranges) - 1
            range_str = array.get(ranges, i)
            is_major = str.contains(range_str, "(major)")
            range_parts = str.split(str.replace(range_str, "(major)", ""), "-")
            lower = str.tonumber(str.trim(array.get(range_parts, 0)))
            upper = str.tonumber(str.trim(array.get(range_parts, 1)))
            
            if not na(lower) and not na(upper)
                range_color = is_support ? (is_major ? color.new(majorSupportColor, 80) : color.new(normalSupportColor, 80)) : (is_major ? color.new(majorResistanceColor, 80) : color.new(normalResistanceColor, 80))
                box_range = box.new(left=bar_index, top=upper, right=bar_index + 100, bottom=lower, bgcolor=range_color, border_width=0)
                label.new(bar_index + 5, (lower + upper) / 2, text="Range: " + str.tostring(lower) + "-" + str.tostring(upper) + (is_major ? " (Major)" : ""), style=label.style_label_down, color=color.new(range_color, 0), textcolor=color.white)

// Only draw on the last bar
if barstate.islast
    draw_levels(support_levels, true)
    draw_levels(resistance_levels, false)
    if show_ranges  // Check if ranges should be drawn
        draw_ranges(support_ranges, true)
        draw_ranges(resistance_ranges, false)

// Debug: Output parsed levels (optional for testing)
if show_debug and bar_index == last_bar_index
    num_extracted_support_ranges = array.size(support_ranges)
    num_extracted_resistance_ranges = array.size(resistance_ranges)
    debug_text = "Support Levels: " + str.tostring(array.size(support_levels)) + "\n" +
                 "Major Support Levels: " + str.tostring(array.size(major_support_levels)) + "\n" +
                 "Resistance Levels: " + str.tostring(array.size(resistance_levels)) + "\n" +
                 "Major Resistance Levels: " + str.tostring(array.size(major_resistance_levels)) + "\n" +
                 "Support Ranges: " + str.tostring(array.size(support_ranges)) + "\n" +
                 "Major Support Ranges: " + str.tostring(array.size(major_support_ranges)) + "\n" +
                 "Resistance Ranges: " + str.tostring(array.size(resistance_ranges)) + "\n" +
                 "Major Resistance Ranges: " + str.tostring(array.size(major_resistance_ranges)) + "\n" +
                 str.tostring(num_extracted_support_ranges) + " Extracted Support Ranges: " + support_extracted_ranges + "\n" +
                 str.tostring(num_extracted_resistance_ranges) + " Extracted Resistance Ranges: " + resistance_extracted_ranges
    
    label.new(bar_index, high, debug_text, color=color.white, textcolor=color.black, size=size.normal)


.

Your script looks fine https://i.imgur.com/utDINqk.png

Hi, thanks for your reply, but the script is not working properly.. I added a new image showing how some labels disappear when I include the ranges. The script has an option to turn the range visualization on and off so I can troubleshoot it.

Your script uses 52 labels. The default value is 50. max_labels_count = 52 is not an option, because your chart would be filled with labels. You need to optimize your code by deleting unused labels (idem box, & lines)
